# How to show that the index of two pairs of groups are equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K \subseteq H \subseteq G$ be finite groups, with $K \triangleleft G$. Show that $H/K = \{Kh \mid h \in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G/K$, and $|G/K : H/K|=|G:H|$.

I have already shown that $H/K$ is a subgroup of $G/K$. The trouble I am having now is show that  $|G/K : H/K|=|G:H|$.

The index $|G:H|$ of $H$ in $G$ is defined to be the number of distinct right (or left)  cosets of $H$ in $G$.

I know that $|G/K : H/K|=\frac{|G/K|}{|H/K|}$ and $|G:H|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ but I am not sure that this helps in any way because $|G/K|$ could be less than $|G|$.

Can someone help get me started on this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it. On one hand :

$$[G:H]=\frac{|G|}{|H|}\text{ and } [G/K:H/K]=\frac{|G/K|}{|H/K|} $$

To do this properly, denote $\pi:G\rightarrow G/K$ the natural projection which is a group morphism. By definition :

$$G/K:=\pi(G)\text{ and } H/K:=\pi(H) $$

Using the fact that $\pi$ is a group morphism, express $|G/K|$ in terms of $|G|$ and $|K|$ and $|H/K|$ in terms of $|H|$ and $|K|$.

Comment: Excellent, G being finite implies that $ |G/K|=|G|/|K|$. I had completely overlooked that theorem. Thank you!